# Why electron defaultPath is not opening the provided directory path

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Hi i'm not able to open the provided directory path(`/home/userxyz/Releases/alpha`) with electron

What i'm trying

1. i have a path like this on ubuntu  `/home/userxyz/Releases/alpha`
2. when i try to open this path with below code

```js
const files = await dialog.showOpenDialog({
    title:'Browse mapped drive',
    defaultPath: "/home/userxyz/Releases/alpha",
    properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']
});
```

3. it is opening some junk directory

**Note:**  i will be having variable  `let openDirectory = "/home/userxyz/Releases/alpha"` which will change based on config value.

**Question:** i want to open a directory with the provided path let say the path will be `/home/userxyz/Releases/alpha`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding successfully opening a `defaultPath`, I have noticed that if the passed-in path does not exist, then either
the last opened path or the valid part of the `defaultPath` (starting from the left) is opened. Therefore, you would want to confirm that
the `defaultPath` exists prior to opening a dialog.

I have included a full but minimised example on how to implement your desired action. Note the use of the `preload.js`
script (via whitelisted channel names only) and
the [ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, ...args)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args)
method in the render process and
the [ipcMain.handle(channel, listener)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener)
method in the main process.

---

I have used the channel name `openFileDialog`.

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': [
            'openFileDialog' // Channel name
        ]
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

See below for further use of the `preload.js` script.

```js
/**
 * Render --> Main
 * ---------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.on('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); })
 *
 * Main --> Render
 * ---------------
 * Main:    windowName.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.receive('channel', (data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Value) --> Render
 * ----------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', (event, data) => { return someMethod(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Promise) --> Render
 * ------------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', async (event, data) => {
 *              return await promiseName(data)
 *                  .then(() => { return result; })
 *          });
 */
```

---

In this `main.js` file, one would want to check that the `defaultPath` exists first, else when the dialog
opens it may be unreliable / appear as a random path.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronDialog = require('electron').dialog;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require("path");

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

// Only pass in a valid defaultPath
let defaultPath = '/home/user/Releases/alpha'; // Ubuntu
// let defaultPath = 'C:\\Users\\user\\invalid\\path'; // Windows

electronIpcMain.handle('openFileDialog', () => {    
    // Dialog options
    let options = {
        title: 'Browse mapped drive',
        defaultPath: defaultPath,
        properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']
    };

    // Open dialog
    return electronDialog.showOpenDialog(window, options)
        .then((result) => {
            // Bail early if user cancelled dialog
            if (result.canceled) { return }

            return result.filePaths;
        })
})
```

---

Detect button `click`, send an IPC message to the main thread which opens the dialog. Upon the dialog returning a value,
it is returned to the render process and displayed as `<li>` items.

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Open File Dialog">

        <ul id="paths"></ul>
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRender.invoke('openFileDialog')
                .then((paths) => {
                    if (paths === undefined) { return } // Dialog was cancelled

                    let result = '';

                    for (let path of paths) {
                        result += '<li>' + path + '</li>';
                    }

                    document.getElementById('paths').innerHTML = result;
                })
        })
    </script>
</html>
```